# Keyboard shortcut for restarting kernel in spyder

Tags: python, spyder

Does anybody know the keyboard shortcut for restarting the kernel in Spyder?

It says it should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>.</kbd> but that is not working. I'm using a norwegian keyboard so I'm thinking it is related to that.

I have tried various combinations of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>something</kbd> to no avail.

Anybody else using a non-US/EN keyboard having this issue? Suggestions? It's not life or death but it would be nice to know the shortcut.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I figured it out.

***The console*** (not the editor or the file explorer or some other part of the interface) has to be selected, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>.</kbd>.

Facepalm.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Some shortcuts only apply when a particular pane is selected and others apply globally. This is declared in the `Context` column of `Tools > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts`.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> works on my Hebrew keyboard so it should also work with the norwegian one.

Answer (score 1):

In the menu bar, click on 'Consoles' than click on 'Restart kernel'.